# Quotient group(Factor group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

Prove that the quotient group  $\frac{Z\times Z\times Z}{<(1,1,1)>}$  is an infinite, non-cyclic group.

Here Z is the group of integers with operation of addition,
$<(1,1,1)$> is the subgroup of $Z\times Z\times Z$ generated by the element $(1,1,1)$

**EDIT (1)-**

I've been able to prove the infiniteness of the group. Here is how I have done it :
 Observe that < [(1,0,0) + < (1,1,1) >]> is an infinite cyclic subgroup of the given group in the question. hence the group in the question is also infinite.

However I am stuck on proving the non-cyclic part.
I'm getting that < [(1,0,0) + < (1,1,1) >] > and < [(0,1,0) + < (1,1,1) > ] > are two cyclic subgroups, whose intersection is {e} that is identity. Can it lead me to anywhere?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you prove that it is infinite? Can you prove that it is not cyclic?

Comment: Yes I have proved that it is infinite. But not been able to prove about non-cyclic nature. Observe that   < [(1,0,0) + < (1,1,1) >]> is an infinite cyclic subgroup of the given group in the question. hence the group on the question is also infinite.

Comment: You should try to demonstrate the following lemma : $G:=\mathbb{Z}^3/<(1,1,1)>$ any element $g$ of $G$ can be written uniquely as $(a,b,0)+<(1,1,1)>$ for $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Clement, I'm trying to prove the same thing but not getting anywhere. :(

Comment: how much more do you need in addition to $<(1,1,1)> \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm getting that < [(1,0,0) + < (1,1,1) >] > and < [(0,1,0) + < (1,1,1) > ] > are two cyclic subgroups, whose intersection is {e} that is identity. Can it lead me to anywhere?

Comment: David, Both the groups that is the Given one and < (1,1,1) > are isomorphic to Z. that's what I know.

Comment: Try to show, that the group elements $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ haven't got "greatest common divisor" in the following mean: there is no $g$ such that $ng=(1,0,0)$ and $mg=(0,1,0)$ for suitable integers $n$ & $m$.

Comment: Leonhardt, I've done that. But what will happen then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would reason like this. A set of representatives for your quotient is
$$\{(0,n,m)+\langle(1,1,1)\rangle\ |\ n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
since $(a,b,c)+\langle(1,1,1)\rangle=(a-a,b-a,c-a)+\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ so
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}{\langle(1,1,1)\rangle}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$

Can you show $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic?

(Assume it's generated by $(n,m)$ and find a contradiction.)

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. :)